HTML output from WordPress shortcode is wrapped in unexpected <p> tags
I'm developing a custom shortcode in WordPress to display a calendar, but I'm encountering an issue where the HTML output is being unexpectedly wrapped in  tags. Here's the code I'm using for the shortcode:
function wp_reservations_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <section>
        <section class="calendar-header">
            <button id="prev-month">Prev</button>
            <div class="current-date">July 2024</div>
            <button id="next-month">Next</button>
        </section>
        <section class="calendar-body">
            <div class="calendar-weekdays"></div>
            <div class="calendar-days"></div>
        </section>
    </section>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('wp_reservations', 'wp_reservations_shortcode');

When I use this shortcode, the HTML output includes unwanted p and br tags like this:
<section>
    <section class="calendar-header">
        <button id="prev-month">Prev</button><p></p>
        <div class="current-date">July 2024</div>
        <p><button id="next-month">Next</button><br></p>
    </section>
    <section class="calendar-body">
        <div class="calendar-weekdays"></div>
        <div class="calendar-days"></div>
    </section>
</section>

I've tried removing the wpautop filter with remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); before returning the HTML, but it didn’t resolve the issue. I attempted to directly echo the HTML output instead of returning it from the shortcode, which also didn't help.
Lastly I tried storing the HTML in a variable and then returning it also failed to remove the p tags.
How can I prevent WordPress from inserting these tags in the output of my shortcode?
Thank you for your help!
Edit:
After further investigation, I've discovered that the issue with unwanted p tags occurs only when the shortcode is used within the site template. When the shortcode is used outside of the template, it functions as expected. Interestingly, other similar plugins do not exhibit this behavior when used in the same context.

Wonder if your template has some malformed HTML.  I know it'll be ugly, but can you try putting your html on a single line? ie. <section class="calendar-header"><button id="prev-month">Prev</button><p></p><div class="current-date">July 2024</div><p><button id="next-month">Next</button><br></p></section>.
Also, FWIW, embedding  in  isn't semantically correct.

Please try as below:
 function wp_reservations_shortcode($atts) {
    // remove auto paragraphs for shortcode content
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <section>
        <section class="calendar-header">
            <button id="prev-month">Prev</button>
            <div class="current-date">July 2024</div>
            <button id="next-month">Next</button>
        </section>
        <section class="calendar-body">
            <div class="calendar-weekdays"></div>
            <div class="calendar-days"></div>
        </section>
    </section>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    // Re-enable automatic paragraphs
    add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    add_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('wp_reservations', 'wp_reservations_shortcode');


Thank you, @danushka, for your suggestions. Unfortunately, the output remains unchanged. I have also tried to change theme to twenty twenty three but without success
